# Problem adding Let's Encrypt SSL to Django App deployed on Heroku

Tags: django, heroku, lets-encrypt

I have a Django application with a paid dyno deployed on Heroku for which I am trying to configure SSL with Let's Encrypt for a custom URL from GoDaddy which points to my Django application deployed on Heroku. I am trying to complete the ACME challenge by going to the URL `http://myapp.com/.well-known/acme-challenge/challenge_list` to generate the certificate but I get the following error in my browser:

> This va-acm.heroku.com page can’t be found. HTTP Error 404

I have installed the `django-letsencrypt` package and it created ACME challenges table in my Django application where I am providing the challenge and response provided from Certbot. I am able to get the response in my local machine `http://127.0.0.1:8000/.well-known/acme-challenge/challenge_list`, but I'm not sure if I am missing some steps to get this working on Heroku.

I have `letsencrypt` in my `settings.py`:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
..........
'letsencrypt',
.........
]
```

My main `urls.py` is as follows:

```
path('.well-known/', include('letsencrypt.urls')),
```

**SYSTEM INFORMATION**

- Django version - 2.0.8
- `django-letsencrypt` - 3.0.1
- Python - 3.6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I strongly advise you to move this out of your application and instead use [Heroku's Automated Certificate Management](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/automated-certificate-management). It uses Let's Encrypt behind the scenes and doesn't have any incremental cost:

> With Automated Certificate Management (ACM), Heroku automatically manages TLS certificates for apps with Hobby and Professional dynos on the Common Runtime, and for apps in Private Spaces that enable the feature.
>
> Certificates handled by ACM automatically renew one month before they expire, and new certificates are created automatically whenever you add or remove a custom domain. All applications with paid dynos include ACM for free.
>
> Automated Certificate Management uses [Let’s Encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/), the free, automated, and open certificate authority for managing your application’s TLS certificates. Let’s Encrypt is run for the public benefit by the [Internet Security Research Group (ISRG)](https://letsencrypt.org/isrg/).

Remove `django-letsencrypt` from your application, redeploy, [make sure your DNS is properly configured](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-domains), and then run `heroku certs:auto:enable`.